# Symbolic solution of system of equations 12x12 takes very long time and the answer is complex too

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions, symbolic

I am trying to solve a system of equation symbolically. It works fine for 6x6, however for 12x12 system it takes very long and the answers are complex. I am using "Solve" or "Reduce". When I write Solve[]//FullSimplify there is no Output.
My question is "is there any efficient way to the following system for a1,a2 ... a6."

```
eq1 = (-η)*Exp[(-j)*k*(d - t)] == a1*η*Exp[(-j)*k*t] - a3*ζ*Exp[j*h3*t] - 
     a4*ζ*Exp[j*h4*t] - a5*ζ*Exp[(-j)*h3*t] - a6*ζ*Exp[(-j)*h4*t]; 
eq2 = 0 == (-a2)*η*Exp[(-j)*k*t] - j*a3*ζ*Exp[j*h3*t] + j*a4*ζ*Exp[j*h4*t] + 
     j*a5*ζ*Exp[(-j)*h3*t] - j*a6*ζ*Exp[(-j)*h4*t]; 
eq3 = 0 == a2*Exp[(-j)*k*t] - j*a3*Exp[j*h3*t] + j*a4*Exp[j*h4*t] - j*a5*Exp[(-j)*h3*t] + 
     j*a6*Exp[(-j)*h4*t]; 
eq4 = Exp[(-j)*k*(d - t)] == a1*Exp[(-j)*k*t] + a3*Exp[j*h3*t] + a4*Exp[j*h4*t] - 
     a5*Exp[(-j)*h3*t] - a6*Exp[(-j)*h4*t]; 
eq5 = (-a3)*ζ - a4*ζ - a5*ζ - a6*ζ + a7*γ + a8*γ + a9*γ + a10*γ == 0; 
eq6 = (-a3)*ζ + a4*ζ + a5*ζ - a6*ζ + a7*γ - a8*γ - a9*γ + a10*γ == 0; 
eq7 = -a3 + a4 - a5 + a6 + a7 - a8 + a9 - a10 == 0; 
eq8 = a3 + a4 - a5 - a6 - a7 - a8 + a9 + a10 == 0; 
eq9 = (-a7)*γ*Exp[(-j)*h1*t] - a8*γ*Exp[(-j)*h2*t] - a9*γ*Exp[j*h1*t] - a10*γ*Exp[j*h2*t] + 
     a11*η*Exp[(-j)*k*t] == 0; 
eq10 = (-j)*a7*γ*Exp[(-j)*h1*t] + j*a8*γ*Exp[(-j)*h2*t] + j*a9*γ*Exp[j*h1*t] - 
     j*a10*γ*Exp[j*h2*t] - a12*η*Exp[(-j)*k*t] == 0; 
eq11 = (-j)*a7*Exp[(-j)*h1*t] + j*a8*Exp[(-j)*h2*t] - j*a9*Exp[j*h1*t] + j*a10*Exp[j*h2*t] - 
     a12*Exp[(-j)*k*t] == 0; 
eq12 = a7*Exp[(-j)*h1*t] + a8*Exp[(-j)*h2*t] - a9*Exp[j*h1*t] - a10*Exp[j*h2*t] + 
     a11*Exp[(-j)*k*t] == 0; 


FullSimplify[Solve[eq1 && eq2 && eq3 && eq4 && eq5 && eq6 && eq7 && eq8 && eq9 && eq10 && 
    eq11 && eq12, {a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, a10, a11, a12}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Your system is linear in a1...a12 correct? It is more helpful to have the equations in a list form and write a[1]...a[12] instead. I've rewritten them like this here: https://pastebin.com/fZ1Ec67R - please verify the equations are correct. From there on you can just solve the linear system directly, though the output is still very large of course.

Comment: Is `j` meant to be `\[ImaginaryJ]`?

Comment: yes that should be imaginary. I don't want to assume any constants.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you replace a few of the complex terms with constants the simplification is done within 15 seconds.

```
reps = {E^(-j k (d - t)) -> c[1], E^(-h1 j t) -> 1/c[2], 
  E^(h1 j t) -> c[2], E^(-h2 j t) -> 1/c[3], E^(h2 j t) -> c[3], 
  E^(-h3 j t) -> 1/c[4], E^(h3 j t) -> c[4], E^(-h4 j t) -> 1/c[5], 
  E^(h4 j t) -> c[5], E^(-j k t) -> 1/c[6]}

sol1 = Solve[eq1 && eq2 && eq3 && eq4 && eq5 && eq6 && eq7 && eq8 && eq9 && 
     eq10 && eq11 && eq12 /. reps, 
     {a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9,
      a10, a11, a12}
] // FullSimplify
```

Then revert the replacements:

```
repsi = #2 -> #1 & @@@ reps;
sol1 /. repsi // FullSimplify
```

Comment: Thank you @ Sjoerd, 
however, I would like to solve it without making any assumptions. I want the unknowns to be in terms of the variables (d, t, h1, h2, h3, h4, gamma, eta, zeta etc..)

Comment: These are not assumptions, just replacement rules. After the simplification you can perform the inverse replacement (just invert all rules).  It works quite well. Just try it.

Comment: See the latest update

Comment: `repsi = Reverse /@ reps`, too.